# wordpress ajax pagination object value does not change

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

i made search plugin inside admin area and this code for search

```
var currpeged =1;
var pperpage=50;
jQuery(document).on('click','#search,#next,#prev',function(e) {
                // click search 
                 e.preventDefault();
                jQuery('.search-result').html('<p class="text-center"><img src="../wp-admin/images/loading.gif"></p>');


                if (jQuery('#showperpage').length == 1 ) {

                    pperpage = parseInt(jQuery('#showperpage').val());
                }

                var id=jQuery(this).attr('id');
                if(id == 'prev'){
                    if(currpeged <= 1){
                        currpeged=1;
                    } else{
                        currpeged-=1;
                    }
                } 

                if(id=='next'){
                    currpeged = currpeged + 1;  
                }
                var srch={
                    filter1:jQuery('#filter1'),
                    filter2:jQuery('#filter2'),
                    currp:currpeged,
                    perpage:pperpage,
                };

                    jQuery.post(ajaxurl,{
                        'action': 'search_do',
                        'param': srch
                    }
                    }).success(function(response){

                    jQuery('.search-result').html('');
                         for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                                jQuery('.search-result').append(response[i]);
                        }
                    });
});
```

and the code for the php that take care of the search is :

```
    $param = $_POST['param'];
  $str_m='';
    if(is_array( $param)){
        $data = new stdClass();
        foreach ($param as $key => $value)
        {
            $data->$key = $value;
        }
    }
     $args_tt=array(); 
     $args=array(); 
     $query = new WP_Query(array( 
     'post_type'       =>    'custom-post',          // name of post type.
     'posts_per_page'  =>     100,
     'orderby'         =>    'meta_value_num',
     'meta_key'        =>    $str_m,
     'order'           =>    'ASC',
     'meta_query'      =>     $args,//filters
     'paged'          =>     intval($data->currp)+1 //from object

    ));
```

when i search  i get results but the paging is not working the currp is never incremented and results still the same as before no pagination please help thank you .

Comment: Filter1: jQuert ?? I mean, maybe a typo, but will break srch and currentp will not be set.

Comment: true but in when results come back from the while loop of WP_Query will have two buttons with #next & #prev and will set the srch again for pagination next page and previous page

Comment: If I understand well, you need to change these values on the success event.

Comment: but i need to change them on click #next or #prev event so that user will be able when they click next and prev button will see the pagination

Answer (score 0):

solution for this question was very simple in js code like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#search',{
//search form submit
});
jQuery(document).on('click','#next',{
//next button clicked build search form + paged value
});
jQuery(document).on('click','#prev',{
//prev button clicked build search form + paged value
});
```